# Gain from threading much less than expected - why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda

I have a function evaluation which is somewhat slow. I'm trying to speed it up by using threading, since there are three things which can be done in parallel. The single-threaded version is

```
return dEdx_short(E) + dEdx_long(E) + dEdx_quantum(E);
```

where evaluation of those functions takes ~250us, ~250us, and ~100us respectively. So I implemented a three-thread solution:

```
double ret_short, ret_long, ret_quantum; // return values for the terms

auto shortF = [this,&E,&ret_short] () {ret_short = this->dEdx_short(E);};
std::thread t1(shortF);
auto longF = [this,&E,&ret_long] () {ret_long = this->dEdx_long(E);};
std::thread t2(longF);
auto quantumF = [this,&E,&ret_quantum] () {ret_quantum = this->dEdx_quantum(E);};
std::thread t3(quantumF);

t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();

return ret_short + ret_long + ret_quantum;
```

Which I expected to take ~300us, yet it actually takes ~600us - basically the same as the single-threaded version! These are all inherently thread-safe so there are no waits for locks. I checked the thread creation time on my system and it's ~25us. I'm not using all of my cores, so I'm a bit baffled as to why the parallel solution is so slow. Is it something to do with the lambda creation?

I tried to bypass the lambda, e.g.:

```
std::thread t1(&StopPow_BPS::dEdx_short, this, E, ret_short);
```

after rewriting the function being called, but that gave me an error `attempt to use a deleted function`...

Comment: Code is often not actually execute-bound.  Memory is frequently the throttle.  Threading buys you more cores, not more memory busses.  Use a good profiler so you can see the cache miss rates.

Comment: Are you doing any IO? For example, if you are reading from a HDD, then you can't really read from it more than once at a time, so you would essentially have threads waiting on eachother still.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking a no-op thread ?

Comment: Good point! Thanks. The two slowest functions are numerical integration, which I assumed would be execute limited without thinking about it...I'll use a profiler

Comment: No IO, and a no-op thread spawns and runs pretty quickly (25us)

Comment: That will sound silly, but... aren't all the threads with the same processor affinity for some reason?

Comment: If the speed is throttled by the instruction cache, then threading won't help performance.

Comment: what hardware is running this code, cause if your machine needs to do context switching often, this might be slower than the actual code that needs to be executed

Comment: 25us for a thread to start, be waited on and be destroyed sounds very fast to me. Are you sure about that number? If the number was 125us instead, that would perfectly explain the timing.

Comment: @Massa Related question, is threading enabled on your compiler?  Perhaps your threads are only actually running once the join() method is called?  Also.. std::async may be more of what you want to use.

Comment: This is definitively the overhead of `std::thread`. The time needed for calculations is way too low to parallelization to give an advantage. You can try creating a thread pool (that eliminates the overhead for construction / destruction) and give the jobs to that pool. Let the threads live a bit longer.

Comment: Yeah, so Hans got me going in the right direction. The sub-methods were all getting hung up on some memory operations, which I optimized. The single-threaded time is now ~400us and the multi-threaded is ~250us which seems reasonable to me, given the longest sub-task takes a little less than 200. This is on a ~year old MBP running 10.8. I did benchmark thread creation/destruction to get the 25us time. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are experiencing [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). To verify, store the return values in a type that uses an entire cache line (size depends on CPU).

```
const int cacheLineSize = 64; // bytes
union CacheFriendly
{
    double value;
    char dummy[cacheLineSize];
} ret_short, ret_long, ret_quantum; // return values for the terms
// ...
```

Comment: wouldn't `union cache_friendly { double value; char dummy[CACHE_LINE_SIZE]; };` be better?

Comment: @Massa Yes, that's less verbose and more generally usable. I've updated my answer with your idea.